# DDR3 MIG Vivado IP

Tags: vhdl, fpga, ram, vivado

I am trying to use MIG 7 to interface a DDR3 ram to an Artix 7 FPGA.
I am very new in using IP and I only know VHDL (not Verilog). I have uploaded my code. In my code the init_calib_complete never goes high !

Anybody can find what is wrong with my code or give me a sample code, please.

-I only use the last few lines for my codes, the rest of that are just declaration.

-I have connected LEDV7 and LEDV6 to LEDs.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
entity Main_PRG is
Port ( 

 -- Inouts
 ddr3_dq                        : inout std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
 ddr3_dqs_p                     : inout std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
 ddr3_dqs_n                     : inout std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);

 -- Outputs
 ddr3_addr                      : out   std_logic_vector(13 downto 0);
 ddr3_ba                        : out   std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
 ddr3_ras_n                     : out   std_logic;
 ddr3_cas_n                     : out   std_logic;
 ddr3_we_n                      : out   std_logic;
 ddr3_reset_n                   : out   std_logic;
 ddr3_ck_p                      : out   std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
 ddr3_ck_n                      : out   std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
 ddr3_cke                       : out   std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
 ddr3_cs_n                      : out   std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
 ddr3_odt                       : out   std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);

 -- Inputs
 -- Differential system clocks
 sys_clk_p                      : in    std_logic;
 sys_clk_n                      : in    std_logic;
 -- Single-ended iodelayctrl clk (reference clock)
 clk_ref_i                                : in    std_logic;

        LEDV6 : out STD_LOGIC ;
        LEDV7 : out STD_LOGIC
        );
end Main_PRG;
architecture Behavioral of Main_PRG is
signal app_addr                    : std_logic_vector(27 downto 0);

signal app_addr                    : std_logic_vector(27 downto 0);
signal app_addr_i                  : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
      signal app_cmd                     : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
      signal app_en                      : std_logic;
      signal app_rdy                     : std_logic;
      signal app_rdy_i                   : std_logic;
  signal app_rd_data                 : std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
  signal app_rd_data_end             : std_logic;
  signal app_rd_data_valid           : std_logic;
  signal app_rd_data_valid_i         : std_logic;
  signal app_wdf_data                : std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
  signal app_wdf_end                 : std_logic;
  signal app_wdf_rdy                 : std_logic;
  signal app_wdf_rdy_i               : std_logic;
  signal app_sr_active               : std_logic;
  signal app_ref_ack                 : std_logic;
  signal app_zq_ack                  : std_logic;
  signal app_wdf_wren                : std_logic;
  signal mem_pattern_init_done       : std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
  signal modify_enable_sel           : std_logic;
  signal data_mode_manual_sel        : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
  signal addr_mode_manual_sel        : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
  signal cmp_error                   : std_logic;
  signal tg_wr_data_counts           : std_logic_vector(47 downto 0);
  signal tg_rd_data_counts           : std_logic_vector(47 downto 0);
  signal init_calib_complete_i       : std_logic;
  signal tg_compare_error_i          : std_logic;
  signal tg_rst                      : std_logic;
  signal po_win_tg_rst               : std_logic;
  signal manual_clear_error          : std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);

  signal clk                         : std_logic;
  signal rst                         : std_logic;

  signal vio_modify_enable           : std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
  signal vio_data_mode_value         : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
  signal vio_pause_traffic           : std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
  signal vio_addr_mode_value         : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
  signal vio_instr_mode_value        : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
  signal vio_bl_mode_value           : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
  signal vio_fixed_instr_value       : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
  signal vio_data_mask_gen           : std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
  signal dbg_clear_error             : std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
  signal vio_tg_rst                  : std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
  signal dbg_sel_pi_incdec           : std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
  signal dbg_pi_f_inc                : std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
  signal dbg_pi_f_dec                : std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
  signal dbg_sel_po_incdec           : std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
  signal dbg_po_f_inc                : std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
  signal dbg_po_f_stg23_sel          : std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
  signal dbg_po_f_dec                : std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
  signal vio_dbg_sel_pi_incdec           : std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
  signal vio_dbg_pi_f_inc                : std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
  signal vio_dbg_pi_f_dec                : std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
  signal vio_dbg_sel_po_incdec           : std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
  signal vio_dbg_po_f_inc                : std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
  signal vio_dbg_po_f_stg23_sel          : std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
  signal vio_dbg_po_f_dec                : std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
  signal all_zeros1                  : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0):= (others => '0');
  signal all_zeros2                  : std_logic_vector(38 downto 0):= (others => '0');
  signal wdt_en_w                    : std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
  signal cmd_wdt_err_w               : std_logic;
  signal wr_wdt_err_w                : std_logic;
  signal rd_wdt_err_w                : std_logic;
signal cntr2                  : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0):= (others => '0');
signal cntr1                  : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0):= (others => '0');


component DDR3_RAM
    port(
  ddr3_dq       : inout std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
  ddr3_dqs_p    : inout std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
  ddr3_dqs_n    : inout std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);

  ddr3_addr     : out   std_logic_vector(13 downto 0);
  ddr3_ba       : out   std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
  ddr3_ras_n    : out   std_logic;
  ddr3_cas_n    : out   std_logic;
  ddr3_we_n     : out   std_logic;
  ddr3_reset_n  : out   std_logic;
  ddr3_ck_p     : out   std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
  ddr3_ck_n     : out   std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
  ddr3_cke      : out   std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
  ddr3_cs_n     : out   std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
  ddr3_odt      : out   std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
  app_addr                  : in    std_logic_vector(27 downto 0);
  app_cmd                   : in    std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
  app_en                    : in    std_logic;
  app_wdf_data              : in    std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
  app_wdf_end               : in    std_logic;
  app_wdf_wren              : in    std_logic;
  app_rd_data               : out   std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
  app_rd_data_end           : out   std_logic;
  app_rd_data_valid         : out   std_logic;
  app_rdy                   : out   std_logic;
  app_wdf_rdy               : out   std_logic;
  app_sr_req                : in    std_logic;
  app_ref_req               : in    std_logic;
  app_zq_req                : in    std_logic;
  app_sr_active             : out   std_logic;
  app_ref_ack               : out   std_logic;
  app_zq_ack                : out   std_logic;
  ui_clk                    : out   std_logic;
  ui_clk_sync_rst           : out   std_logic;
  init_calib_complete       : out   std_logic;
  -- System Clock Ports
  sys_clk_p                      : in    std_logic;
  sys_clk_n                      : in    std_logic;
  -- Reference Clock Ports
  clk_ref_i                                : in    std_logic;
  sys_rst             : in std_logic
  );
end component DDR3_RAM;

----------------------------------------------------------
---DDR RAM Interface signals
----------------------------------------------------------
CONSTANT READ_CMD   : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0) := "001";
CONSTANT WRITE_CMD  : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0) := "000";

signal data_1 : std_logic_vector (63 downto 0); 
signal data_2 : std_logic_vector (63 downto 0);

    type state_machine is (Init, Write_1, Set_Data_1, Write_2, Set_Data_2,
  Read_Prep_1, Read_1, Read_Wait_1, Read_Prep_2, Read_2, Read_Wait_2, 
 Done);
 signal state        : state_machine := Init;
 signal next_state   : state_machine;

 signal Curr_State   : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0):="000";  
 signal Reset        : std_logic := '0' ;  
 begin 
u_DDR3_RAM : DDR3_RAM
  port map (
   -- Memory interface ports
   ddr3_addr                      => ddr3_addr,
   ddr3_ba                        => ddr3_ba,
   ddr3_cas_n                     => ddr3_cas_n,
   ddr3_ck_n                      => ddr3_ck_n,
   ddr3_ck_p                      => ddr3_ck_p,
   ddr3_cke                       => ddr3_cke,
   ddr3_ras_n                     => ddr3_ras_n,
   ddr3_reset_n                   => ddr3_reset_n,
   ddr3_we_n                      => ddr3_we_n,
   ddr3_dq                        => ddr3_dq,
   ddr3_dqs_n                     => ddr3_dqs_n,
   ddr3_dqs_p                     => ddr3_dqs_p,
   init_calib_complete            => init_calib_complete_i,
   ddr3_cs_n                      => ddr3_cs_n,
   ddr3_odt                       => ddr3_odt,
-- Application interface ports
   app_addr                       => app_addr,
   app_cmd                        => app_cmd,
   app_en                         => app_en,
   app_wdf_data                   => app_wdf_data,
   app_wdf_end                    => app_wdf_end,
   app_wdf_wren                   => app_wdf_wren,
   app_rd_data                    => app_rd_data,
   app_rd_data_end                => app_rd_data_end,
   app_rd_data_valid              => app_rd_data_valid,
   app_rdy                        => app_rdy,
   app_wdf_rdy                    => app_wdf_rdy,
   app_sr_req                     => '0',
   app_ref_req                    => '0',
   app_zq_req                     => '0',
   app_sr_active                  => app_sr_active,
   app_ref_ack                    => app_ref_ack,
   app_zq_ack                     => app_zq_ack,
   ui_clk                         => clk,
   ui_clk_sync_rst                => rst,
-- System Clock Ports
   sys_clk_p                       => sys_clk_p,
   sys_clk_n                       => sys_clk_n,
-- Reference Clock Ports
   clk_ref_i                      => clk_ref_i,
    sys_rst                        => '1'
    );
-- End of User Design top instance





process(clk)
begin
    if  rising_edge(clk) then
       if cntr1(27) = '0' then
         cntr1 <= cntr1 + 1 ;
       end if;    
    end if ;
end process ;      


Reset <= cntr1(28) ;

process (clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
    if init_calib_complete_i = '1' then
        LEDV6 <= '1' ;
        LEDV7 <= '0' ;
    else
        LEDV6 <= '1' ;
        LEDV7 <= '1' ;
    end if;    
        if Reset = '0' then
            app_en       <= '0';
            app_wdf_wren <= '0';
            app_wdf_end  <= '0';
            app_cmd      <= (others => '0');
            app_addr     <= (others => '0');
            app_wdf_data <= (others => '0');
            state <= Init;
        else
            app_en       <= '0';
            app_wdf_wren <= '0';
            app_wdf_end  <= '0';

            app_cmd      <= (others => '0');
            app_addr     <= (others => '0');
            app_wdf_data <= (others => '0');


            --LEDV6 <= '1' ;
            --LEDV7 <= '1' ;


            case state is
                when Init =>
                    Curr_State <= "001";
                    data_1 <= (others => '0');
                    data_2 <= (others => '0');

                    --LEDV6 <= '1' ;
                    --LEDV7 <= '0' ;


                    if app_rdy = '1' then
                        state <= Write_1;
                    else 
                        state <= Init;
                    end if;
                when Write_1 =>

                    --LEDV6 <= '0' ;
                    --LEDV7 <= '0' ;

                when others =>
                    --LEDV6 <= '0' ;
                    --LEDV6 <= '0' ;


                end case;

        end if ;                
    end if;
end process;                        

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: `init_calib_complete` is an output of the instantiated `DDR3_RAM` external block which is not in evidence in your code. Your question is so not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) tells us asking for examples is off-topic, too. According to UG586 "The application has no need to wait for init_calib_complete before sending commands to the Memory Controller".  We don't see a testbench with a RAM model either. Any sign calibration is occurring?

Comment: signal `app_addr` is declared twice, which should produce an error. How closely does this represent your code?

Comment: When you say it "never goes high", how long is your simulation? I haven't tried MIG with DDR3 but it's not so different from DDR2. And with DDR2 the calibration phase took between 50us and 100 us - quite a long sim run - with a model of a DDR2 memory component in the testbench. It won't terminate at all if there isn't a memory model to calibrate against. And you won't find a VHDL model anywhere for DDR2 or 3 (I'd love to be proved wrong!) so you'll have to use a Verilog model. And the old ISIM version I used, would only allow a single Verilog component in a VHDL testbench. (Maybe fixed now)

Comment: The code executed, without any error. 
when I implement it directly to the FPGA. it doesn't matter how long pass, it never goes high. i have waited over 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks every body
I found I have problem with clock. Since *ui_clk_sync_rst* signal was always low, I guessed it must be clock problem. In my design, I have a 27 MHz and a 25 MHz input clocks. MIG-7, Does not let the user assign generated clock with internal PLL as reference and system clocks due to jitter problem. 
For external clock the minimum input clock has to be 50MHz. 
But there is a solution. The solution is to change the generated IP. 
Thanks everyone.

Comment: I also just tripped over the limitation also mentioned in UG586 that no internally generated clock can be used for the MIG. What do you mean by "the solution is to change the generated IP"? Did you manage to get MIG working with a synthesized clock anyway or did you write your own controller?

Comment: @Amir Finally, how did you guys get MIG working with the synthesized clock?

Answer (score 3):

A few suggestions:

1. Check if sys_rst input to the MIG is active HI (this can be configured to be either active LO or HI when configuring the IP core).  If this is true, tying it to '1' would keep the MIG in reset and init_calib_complete would never go high.
2. Create an ILA (integrate logic analyzer) and add ui_clk_sync_rst to it.  Check if this ever deasserts
3. If you have the AC701 dev kit, you can follow the MIG tutorial at:

http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/boards_and_kits/ac701/2015_1/xtp225-ac701-mig-c-2015-1.pdf

This is an known working design provided by Xilinx.  Although I haven't worked with the Artix7, I was able to get Xilinx's example design to work on the VC707 with the Virtex7 with no issues.

4. If you have a custom board, refer to the section "Debugging DDR3/DDR2 Designs in Chapter 1 of:

http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/mig_7series/v2_0/ug586_7Series_MIS.pdf

I believe you can port Xilinx's example design to any custom board as long as you follow their guidelines such as pinouts, clocks, etc.